# SQL Server Sum Issue weird behaviour

Tags: sql, sql-server, t-sql

This is my issues. This query will calculate the total Cash and credit card for the day "Cashup". Easy Right!

The same query returned 2 different results.

In Store in showed 1246.00 "In Correct"

When I go back run the this query again on that server

I get 1384.00 "Correct"

The Date Field are DateTime Data Types and Cash/CreditCard is Money.
None of the above fields allow null.

```
SELECT Sum(Payments.PaymentCash)   AS cash,
       Sum(Payments.PaymentCredit) AS CreditCards
FROM   Sales
       INNER JOIN Payments
               ON Sales.SaleID = Payments.SaleID
WHERE  Sales.StoreID = 3
       AND Sales.SaleTillNumber = 1
       AND Payments.PaymentDate > '2015-10-20 19:09:48.000'
       AND Payments.PaymentDate < '2015-10-22 08:29:52.120'
```

How would this be possible? Any ideas...

Comment: Is the table being updated in between your two queries?  I consider an increase in sales to be a good thing ^ ^

Comment: No, nothing gets added to sales in that period because its just a cash up procedure.

Comment: I don't see how this could be happening unless the database is getting updated in between your two visits.

Answer (score 1):

This query is fully deterministic, so the result changes only if the underlying data changes. Rows are being either added, deleted, or updated to either the `Sales` or `Payments` tables.

I don't know your data or the UI that accesses these tables, but bear in mind slightly unexpected situations like:

- Negative values in `PaymentCash` or `PaymentCredit` columns (which would cause the sum to increase if they're deleted) - unless you have constraints on the columns, this would be possible.
- Updates to rows that change the `SaleTillNumber` or `StoreId` column values - which would cause additional data to be included.

If you have columns on either/both tables that record the last time the row was changed, then you could examine these to look for edits in between the two runs of the query. If you don't, you could add such a column and maintain it via a trigger on each table. You can also capture the database user responsible for the edit in the same way. (Bear in mind that this could have a negative effect on transactional access to the tables.)

You could also explore SQL Server logging to identify such changes.